# How to get the value from this json string?

Tags: javascript, json

```
success: function(data){   alert(data[0].data.AVG(Rate)); }
```

How can I alert 7.5? I have tried data[0].data.AVG(Rate), data.data.AVG(Rate), data.AVG(Rate)

```
([{"data":{"AVG(Rate)":"7.5"}}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alert(data[0].data["AVG(Rate)"]);
```

If this is what data looks like (array of objects):

```
var data = [
    {
        "data": {
            "AVG(Rate)": "7.5"
        }
    }
];
```

The key is what your key looks like: `AVG(Rate)`

This has parenthesis, so JS will try to call the AVG function if you try to access it with `.` notation, which doesn't work. You'll need to use the bracket syntax to avoid the syntax problems.

In the futute, I recommend using only alphanumeric (with at least one letter leading) characters only in keys.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you :)

```
<script>
    var data = $.parseJSON('[{"data":{"AVG(Rate)":"7.5"}}]');
    alert(data[0]['data']['AVG(Rate)']);
</script>
```

Comment: There's no need to parse the JSON - jQuery will have already done that by the time it calls the success handler, and it will pass the resulting object. (Of course, I'm assuming jQuery is what the OP is using, but then you've assumed that too with `$.parseJSON()`.)